# Generic function which accepts T.Type or [T].Type as parameter and return T

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to write a generic function which accepts Generic `T.Type` as function argument, but it is not accepting `T.Type` as array

```
public protocol Mappable {
    
}

class User: Mappable {
    var name: String?
}

class MyClass {
    func request<T: Mappable>(responseType: T.Type) -> T {
        let objT = .....
        return objT
    }
}
let myCls = MyClass()
myCls.request(responseType: User.self) // Works as expected
myCls.request(responseType: [User].self) // Error: Instance method 'request(responseType:)' requires that '[User]' conform to 'Mappable'
```

**Experiment:**
If I replace `Mappable` with `Decodable` in above code, it works fine. but I want to use my `Protocol` and not `Decodable`

I want to achieve similar to

```
struct Car: Decodable {
    var name: String?
}

let data = "{\"name\": \"Lamborghini\"}".data(using: .utf8)
let dataArray = "[{\"name\": \"Lamborghini\"}, {\"name\": \"Ferrari\"}]".data(using: .utf8)

let car = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Car.self, from: data!) // Will return single object of Car
let cars = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Car].self, from: dataArray!) // Will return Array of Car
```

I am not able to figure out why it works with `Decodable` and not with my `Mappable` `Protocol`

Comment: At the moment both the protocol and the generic method do nothing. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? `Codable` is robust, reliable and optimized.

Comment: @vadian Mappable is not my own protocol, my codebase is old and it uses ObjectMapper for mapping. Migration from ObjectMapper to Codable is not option for me at-least now.

Comment: This is still worse. `ObjectMapper` has become obsolete in favor of `Codable`. Consider to do the migration. It's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the array is decodable if it's element type is decodable.

```
extension Array: Decodable where Element: Decodable {
  /// Creates a new array by decoding from the given decoder.
  ///
  /// This initializer throws an error if reading from the decoder fails, or
  /// if the data read is corrupted or otherwise invalid.
  ///
  /// - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()

    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    while !container.isAtEnd {
      let element = try container.decode(Element.self)
      self.append(element)
    }
  }
}
```

you can refer the implementation from https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift

I think your function call `myCls.request(responseType: [User].self)` is failed because T is [User], it's not a Mappable.